# Drag and drop image, returns wrong size

Tags: jquery, css, drag-and-drop, html5-canvas

Im using a pre-made script to drag images from computer folders, and into a div (see JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/JtJ5N/1/). Script works fine, but I have a problem retrieving the image size - the first time for a new image.

What is weird, is that the first time i drag the image into the div, it returns height(24) and width(24), which is not correct. BUT, if I reload the page, and drag the same image again, the size is correct!

First time dragging a new picture into div:

[image: first]

Second time dragging the same picture, after reloading page:

[image: first]

Doesn't make any sense to me, as nothing should be saved. Please see JSFiddle example above, and the only additional code is the size-retrieval as following:

```
list.appendChild(img);
var imgheight = img.height;
var imgwidth = img.width;
alert("width: " + imgwidth + ", height: " + imgheight);
```

Comment: Did you get this fixed?

Comment: Nope, not yet, I tried with `imgwidth = $("#list").children("img").width();` but it returns the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem lies in image not loading. When you refresh / reload the page, the image is in browser cache and hence, when the code executes to read its width x height, it already knows the image and gives you correct answer.

Please check the [FIDDLE HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/JtJ5N/128/) for a solution. This code gives an alert whenever an image is dropped with image's different details.

Please look out for following code:

```
 var dummyimage = new Image();
```

and then

```
                dummyimage.src = e.target.result;
                dummyimage.onload = function() {
                    // to add loaded image to document
                    list.appendChild(dummyimage);
                    // various properties of image
                    alert('width:' + this.width + ' x height:' + this.height + ' --- ' + file.type + '  ' + file.name  + '  ' + file.size);
                };
                dummyimage.onerror= function() {
                    alert('Image could not be loaded');
                };
```

The code also let you know if there is a problem in loading an image. E.g. if a .doc file is dropped or something.

Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Thank you - this seems to work! At least it gets the image size, but it seems that code below this doesn't get executed. It seems like everything in the `addEventHandler(reader, 'loadend', function(e, file)` is processed until your function here, but nothing after it.

Comment: Can you please elaborate?  Can you provide a sample code ? **BTW,** if the above answer has solved your actual question, then you should accept it. So that other answer seekers can see this as accepted answer and get guidance form it as well as it increases the answered question %.

Comment: Sorry for late reply. I solved this by stripping the `dummyimage.onload`-function, and just getting the image height/width after `dummyimage.src` is set. Thanks!